# alternative to image attribute height:auto

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with getting my website to display correctly in IE. All other browsers display it just fine I have narrowed down the problem to the image attribute I set in an image tag, which is `height="auto"` if I set the value of `height` to a static value like 150px it will display the picture but not proportionally like I would want it to. Is there an alterative method I am new at this and have tried searching for the answer but could not find what I am in search of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I deleted the `height` attribute and it worked just fine.